# Is possible to use Coherence as a cache layer between PHP App and Oracle DB?

Tags: architecture, oracle-coherence

Oracle Coherence has a great feature [1](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH35UG/Read-Through,+Write-Through,+Write-Behind+and+Refresh-Ahead+Caching) to support intensive read-only and read-write operations when it is used as a distributed cache layer between your App and the backend relational database storage. But I would like to know if has anyone considered using this approach in a PHP critical app context.

Any information will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly valid. Enough of this SO policing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Oracle Coherence REST API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22839/rest_example.htm) to access the cluster.  The REST API supports HTTP GET, PUT, POST and DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

One of the great features of Coherence is the ability to receive notification about data entering certain state (or added/removed/updated to the cache). Without using Java, .NET or C++ APIs (provided by Oracle) you can't leverage it. However, over REST API you should be able to leverage the faster access (cumulatively, not per-call) to persistent data stores.